# Selecting a specific node in JSON using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: json, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, rackspace-cloudfiles

Hopefully an easy question for you.

I have an API service from Rackspace which I call, recently they changed the order of some of the responses, meaning part of my app would no longer upload images to the correct POST url.

I've put a temp fix in place by hard coding the URL's it should be posting to, but I want to be sure I future proof against any changes in their API ordering or indeed any changes to the URL itself.

So, originally I was using the JSON response and choosing the first node and its children.

```
var CFtenantID = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[0].endpoints[0].tenantId;
var CFregion = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[0].endpoints[0].region;
var CFpublicURL = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[0].endpoints[0].publicURL;
```

Now, that node has moved to position 18 in a long list. So, I can manually set the script to retrieve it.

```
   var CFtenantID = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].tenantId;
   var CFregion = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].region;
   var CFpublicURL = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].publicURL;
```

What I'd like to be able to do, is scan for the "name" instead and just return the CloudFiles info I need, rather than having to declare an actual number of the array.

Here is a snippet of the JSON response from Rackspace.

```
{
                "name": "cloudFeeds",
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "region": "LON",
                        "tenantId": "1234",
                        "publicURL": "https://lon.feeds.api.rackspacecloud.com/1234",
                        "internalURL": "https://atom.prod.lon3.us.ci.rackspace.net/1234"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "rax:feeds"
            },
            {
                "name": "cloudFiles",
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "region": "LON",
                        "tenantId": "MossoCloudFS_xxxxxx",
                        "publicURL": "https://storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_xxxxx",
                        "internalURL": "https://snet-storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_xxxxx"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "object-store"
            },
            {
                "name": "cloudFilesCDN",
                "endpoints": [
                    {
                        "region": "LON",
                        "tenantId": "MossoCloudFS_xxxxxx",
                        "publicURL": "https://cdn3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_xxxxxx"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "rax:object-cdn"
            }
```

And here is my overall script in Appcelerator.

```
var authCloudFiles = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
                    onload: function() {
                        // output
                        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);

                        var getRSToken = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                        var rsToken = getRSToken.access.token.id;
                        var rsTenantID = getRSToken.access.token.tenant.id;
                        var rsTenantName = getRSToken.access.token.tenant.name;
                        var CFtenantID = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].tenantId;
                        var CFregion = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].region;
                        var CFpublicURL = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].publicURL;
                        var rsUserID = getRSToken.access.user.id;

                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('rsToken', rsToken);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('rsTenantID', rsTenantID);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('rsTenantName', rsTenantName);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('CFtenantID', CFtenantID);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('CFregion', CFregion);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('CFpublicURL', CFpublicURL);
                        Ti.App.Properties.setString('rsUserID', rsUserID);

                        //alert(rsToken);
                        Ti.API.info('rsToken: ' + rsToken);
                        Ti.API.info('rsTenantID: ' + rsTenantID);
                        Ti.API.info('rsTenantName: ' + rsTenantName);
                        Ti.API.info('CFtenantID: ' + CFtenantID);
                        Ti.API.info('CFregion: ' + CFregion);
                        Ti.API.info('CFpublicURL: ' + CFpublicURL);
                        Ti.API.info('rsUserID: ' + rsUserID);

                        // then we need to load the next step
                        rackspaceUpload();
                    }
                });
                authCloudFiles.open('POST', 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens');
```

Can anyone help?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Appcelerator Titanium before, but it looks like it is just JavaScript.

You could try replacing the following:

```
var CFtenantID = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].tenantId;
var CFregion = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].region;
var CFpublicURL = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog[17].endpoints[0].publicURL;
```

with:

```
var CFtenantID = "";
var CFregion = "";
var CFpublicURL = "";
var catalog = getRSToken.access.serviceCatalog;
for (var i=0; i<catalog.length; i++) {
  if (catalog[i].name == "cloudFiles") {
    for (var j=0; i<catalog[i].endpoints.length; j++) {
      if (catalog[i].endpoints[j].region == "LON") {
        CFtenantID = catalog[i].endpoints[j].tenantId;
        CFregion = catalog[i].endpoints[j].region;
        CFpublicURL = catalog[i].endpoints[j].publicURL;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My JavaScript is a little rusty though, you may want to add some additional error handling.